# How can I limit my facebook app to only users from the USA?

Tags: ruby, facebook, location

I am using ruby + sinatra and the koala gem to make a facebook iframe app.
I would like to find out where each user is and not allow them to access my app if they are outside the USA.
Requiring the user_location permission only returns a city to me, not a country, and can also be set by the user in their facebook settings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this in the app's advanced settings.

Insert your app id into the URL below where it says "YOUR_APP_ID"
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/advanced

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I looked over that.